# How to avoid multiple instances of forms in compact framework

Tags: forms, frameworks, windows-mobile, navigation, instances

I am making a mobile application in compact framework 3.5 for windows mobile 6.5.

The architecture of the application is such that after login the user can see main menu from where he see many options. My application has atleast 40 forms and i have buttons on each of my form for navigation. The problem i am facing is that in the task manager i see multiple forms open and this list continuous to grow as we navigate across the forms

I am looking for a simple solution or any tip from friends out there

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do is that I use a single Form that contains several UserControls to represent my work flow. I only use Forms to contain UserControls, I can re-use these UserControls in other forms, but they won't always be the same instance. By doing it this way, I can dispose of my form once I have completed or cancelled the specific work flow.

Here's an example:

A Form called ManualPickingForm contains the following UserControls:
  1. ScanPallet
  2. ScanColli
  3. ScanPartNumber
  4. Display Summary

In the form I describe above I can use the following work flow

Scan Pallet -> Scan Colli -> Scan Part Number -> Display Summary -> Finished? No... -> Scan Pallet -> ...... -> Finished? Yes -> Close Form

You can control the behavior of the UserControls through the container form